# A typical Magento SE user

Tags: discussion

Recent days I came across a typical [user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/17110/vaibhav-ahalpara) who's questions (70% of his questions) which will be voted to close.And look at this particular [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49177/404-error-with-my-system-xml-file/49359#49359) asked by him,then he voted to close and he answered the question,in my opinion he created account just to gain reputation but not knowledge.I request moderators to look into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he's in it for the rep, he's not doing a very good job so far, I guess.
I admit that some of his questions are too broad or unclear, but most of them seam to me like good questions coming from a beginner. I remember I had a few of those questions when I started working with Magento. Unfortunately there was no one to answer them.
Here is [one example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/48800/146) and [the second](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/48486/146).
I see no reason for now to suspend his account, but please flag or vote to close for the questions that you don't find appropriate for this website (from this user or any other one).

Comment: Yea I accept what you said and BTW I didn't ask him to be suspended but his behaviour seems little different which I noticed so far.